# Viewing mounted docker container in browser

Tags: web-applications, docker, containers

I have a created a mounted container using the following:

```
docker run --privileged -di -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -v /home/nshneor/workspace/manageiq:/var/www/miq/vmdb manageiq/manageiq
```

Unfortunately I am not able to view the app through `https://localhost`

When I'm not mounting the container on a local dir i.e create the container using:

```
docker run --privileged -di -p 80:80 -p 443:443 manageiq/manageiq
```

I am able to view it in `https://localhost`

Any ideas as to why this is happening?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the container has the right permissions for that directory.
Check it by loging in inside the container.

docker exec -t [container-name] /bin/bash

Comment: yes I am sure. I am able to run bash inside the container - also when i add a file/change a file in my local dir i can see the change (using the above command) inside the container - its just a matter of viewing it in the browser.

Comment: The question is if the container can read/write the files inside that directory. If not it explains why you cannot see the website.
While inside the container can you copy files to that directory and remove them with the user used by the application?